# Algorithm to read numbers from a .txt file and print the numbers in a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, foreach

I have a foreach loop in a PHP code which processes 2000 `.txt` files from a folder, for example:

```
    $files = glob('files/*.txt');
foreach($files as $file) {
    $rand = rand(5000,10000); 
    $file_name  = basename($file, ".txt");
    echo $file .$rand. $number. '.txt' ."<br>";
// Number should be read from the number.txt file
}
```

Assume that there is a `number.txt` file that `$number` variable is read from in the above example (each number is in one row, see the below picture). Also, assume that we don’t know whether the total number of rows is greater or smaller than 2000. So my question is how to write an algorithm which satisfies the below conditions:

1. If there are more than 2000 listed numbers in the `number.txt` file, the code prints any number where none of them is duplicated.

2. If there are less than 2000 numbers in the `number.txt` file, the code prints all listed numbers at least once where it can print duplicated numbers until the foreach loop ends.

[image: number.txt file]

Comment: Did you try something before asking, and if yes, what, and where did you get stuck ? If no, do it.

Comment: @X.L.Ant, thank you for your comment. I edited the example code to make my question more clear. Shall I use the traditional `fopen` method to echo the `$number`?

Comment: @X.L.Ant, I used `$handle = fopen("file-number/number.txt", "r");` 
`$number = fgets($handle);`, but it just prints the first line of the file. How to read the file line by line and repeat this process until the foreach loop is completed?

Answer (score 1):

Should get you started:

```
$files = glob("files/*.txt");

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $lines = file($file);

    if(count($lines) >= 2000) {
        $lines = array_unique($lines);
    }
    foreach($lines as $number) {
        echo $number;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I edited the code in the question. Could you please provide me more information on how to echo the `$number` from the `number.txt` file based on your answer? thanks,